# How to set maximum duration when recording audio in android using an intent

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, max

Hi i am recording audio in android using the following intent

```
public void onClick (View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Intent intent =
                       new     Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);                 
               startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
           }});
           }
```

i have tried 
    set max duration 
but it doesn't work please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

For video I know you can use 
`intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 30000);` (substituting 30000 for the length you  need). I recommend giving this a try.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work going through d.android.com trying to figure it out